# Stringbuilder containing html to CSV

Tags: c#, html, csv, stringbuilder

I have a stringbuilder object that contains html table. I want to write this string into a CSV file. Problem is that the CSV file shows the HTML tags as such. Is there a solution for this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("<html> <table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" >");
            sb.AppendFormat("<tr style =\"color:black;\">");
            sb.AppendFormat("<td style=\"border-color:black; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; \">" + "ColumnValue1" + " </td>");
            sb.AppendFormat("<td style=\"border-color:black; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; mso-number-format:'0' \">" + "ColumnValue2" + "</td>"); 
            sb.AppendFormat("</table></html>");

            File.WriteAllText("file.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Why you want to enter html in csv file anyway?

Comment: I actually need the ColumnValue2 to appear as number instead of exponent when i open the file in excel.

Comment: Is there another way to have the value appear as number in the CSV file without involving a table?

Comment: do you want the contents of the table without Html markup?

Comment: yes, but with the formatting intact

Comment: So if the table has two columns you expect to get two column CSV, correct? However html you posted is incorrect, `tr` tag is not being closed.

Comment: yes, please ignore the code. i want the columns to appear in CSV, with the 2nd column displayed as number, instead of exponent

Comment: yes, but this is not valid html and it's not clear were you got that table from.

Comment: How does that matter??

Comment: `StringBuilder` can build strings - period. There is **nothing** in it, that can recognize what the strings will represent. So `StringBuilder` can **not** convert from any format into another format, otherwise MS had named it different like `MagicalAnyTextFormatConverter`.

Comment: It works perfectly when the file i create has an extension of xls. The problem arises when i create a CSV file. So am asking is there a way to create a CSV file, with ColumnValue2 formatted as a string instead of exponent, that doesnt involve stringbuilder or html?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am looking for a similar solution.